# The plural of "noun of noun", three types of combination

Tags: grammatical-number

Just wondering what's the plural form of "noun of noun". Should the 's' be added to the first noun or the second, or both?

Example: we will examine the 'concentration of heavy metal' in this paper.

**concentrations of heavy metals.** 
*Does this indicate each heavy metal has more than one concentration?*

**concentrations of heavy metal.**
 *Only one type of heavy metal, and has many concentrations?*

**concentration of heavy metals.** 
*Does this indicate there are many types of heavy metals and each has only one concentration?*

I found the 3 types of plural forms all exist in academic papers.

Comment: Great question! Could you add the '3 types' you found to your question, it may help people that are answering it.

Comment: In your field, is the term *heavy metals* used as a [plurale tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) in that context - in particular, without an article (a/an/the)? If so, your second example sounds like something to do with a type of sound that some call music and others call noise.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Irregular plurals in noun adjuncts](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203026/), but that earlier question has no accepted or upvoted answers.

Comment: I think it's real meaning is the concentration that ensues when listening to heavy metal ;)

Comment: A complicating factor is that both of these nouns have both count and non-count usages.

Comment: @Lawrence heavy metal here means a class of pollutant, not a genre of music, it is a countable noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me,

- "concentration of heavy metals" means "the overall concentration of all heavy metals taken as a collective in a single sample"
- "concentrations of heavy metals" means either "the collection of the individual concentrations of each heavy metal in a single sample" or "the collection of the concentration(s) of heavy metal(s) in multiple samples"
- "Concentrations of heavy metal" seems to mean only "the collection of the concentration(s) of heavy metal(s) in multiple samples." Like @Lawrence above, I'm surprised at the use of the singular in this case, though, given the way "heavy metal" is usually used to describe a particular elements membership in a class. Maybe if it were referring to the musical genre?

I am not a chemist.

Comment: You have some irregularities in your second bullet point, I think you wanted to refer to the third of the question but you didn't, it's the same as your last point.

Answer (score 1):

"Concentration of heavy metals"
Concentration is the amount of a substance in a solution. Therefore, concentration of heavy metals should refer to a SPECIFIC AMOUNT of a substance in a solution of the metals.
However, "Concentrations of heavy metals" may refer to an UNSPECIFIC AMOUNT of a substance in a solution of the metals.
This's my understanding as a Chemist.
Thanks.