# Should you say "job status" or "jobs status"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, grammatical-number

I have a web application that displays the status of batch processing jobs on our computer cluster. To me, the title should read:

> Job status

not

> Job**s** status

but I really don't know why and I'm not sure I'm right. Could you kindly explain?

Comment: I am thinking of a tabular personnel chart, whose columns are headed *name*, *address*, *date of birth*, etc. I wouldn't consider pluralising those, even though they head lists of many names. Is this a parallel situation to what you have in mind?

Comment: Do you mean the status of individual jobs, or the aggregate status of all jobs?

Comment: @HotLicks : both actually. The interface gives you aggregate numbers, but allows you to display individual jobs as well.

Comment: *Jobs status* doesn't make sense but *Jobs' statuses* could. Nonetheless, I'd still opt with *job status*.

Comment: In the US, "job status".  For all I know, other places may vary.

Comment: This is a difficult topic to search for, but it is also (or perhaps for exactly that reason it is) one of the most asked-about topics on this site. As far as I can tell, most of the questions marked as duplicates consider [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account) the ‘base question’.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the phrase, *job* is an attributive noun: a noun functioning as an adjective qualifying *status*.

In English, adjectives are not inflected for number. In the phrase *red apples,* the adjective *red* doesn't alter depending on the number of apples; neither does it alter if the apples are different shades of red (so there is more than one red).

Thus: **Job status.** There may be different statuses, and different jobs, but *job* here doesn't get inflected: it's acting as an adjective.

There are those who support the demise of the possessive apostrophe; who maintain it's acceptable to talk of *childrens clothes, mens wear* instead of *children's clothes* and *men's wear* (as opposed to the compound nouns *childrenswear, menswear,* which can't have an apostophe in the middle). On this basis, *Jobs status* might be acceptable for *Jobs' status:* using the apostrophe is fussy and could even lead to confusion with the late Steve Jobs.

However, having two *s* together in the middle of the phrase looks odd and it's not easy to say distinctly. There's not much difference between saying *jobs status* and *job status*. Purely on practical grounds in this case, it's another character in a column heading.

Given that using an apostrophe seems overly fussy, omitting it is still currently disputed, and the singular *job* is understandable and justifiable, use *Job status.*

Comment: Note that the missing apostrophe in the examples you give is also related to the [tendency to use irregular plurals in compounds](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203026/irregular-plurals-in-noun-adjuncts) where regular nouns would use the singular. _Jobs’ status(es)_, with or without an apostrophe, sounds and reads almost bizarre to me, though _men’s status(es)_ is fine.

Comment: @J Hmm. Certainly I wouldn't use *Man status*! Perhaps a little more finesse is required in an answer to the question. (Feel free!)

Comment: I’d say if it meant anything, _man status_ would be the current status of someone’s attempt to become (like?) a man. I suppose it could be a rather crude way of referring to the progress of someone undergoing gender-reassignment treatment.